# How to do mass variable assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash like this:

```
user_info = {
    user_id: 1,
    first_name: "Henry",
    last_name: "Avery",
    phone_number: 1234567890,
    address: "United Kingdom",
}
```

When I receive this hash, I need to assign many variables like this:

```
user_id = user_info[:user_id]
first_name = user_info[:first_name]
last_name = user_info[:last_name]
phone_number = user_info[:phone_number]
address = user_info[:address]
```

It's annoying, and makes the code have more unnecessary lines. Even if I put all of them into one sentence, it'll be messy, the line being too long:

```
user_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, address = user_info[:user_id], user_info[:first_name], user_info[:last_name], user_info[:phone_number], user_info[:address]
```

Do you know a quicker way to assign the hash to variables?
Thank you.

Comment: No, that's about the best you can get, without compromising security.

Comment: excuse me, what about the security in this case ?

Comment: To shorten this code any further, one would have to forego explicit listing of the attributes and the code would become "take whatever is in that hash and make some variables from it". This is especially dangerous with dynamic local variables, which I'm pretty sure you have to use `eval` for (which should not be used unless precautions are made and there's a legitimate reason, which is not the case here).

Comment: I got your idea. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Having many local variables is usually a code smell. Why do you need them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
user_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, address = user_info[:user_id], user_info[:first_name], user_info[:last_name], user_info[:phone_number], user_info[:address]
```

could be

```
user_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, address = user_info.values_at(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address)
```

Although it's long as well, I know

Comment: Thank you very much, your method is so impressive

Comment: My pleasure Sir :) Anyway, I have to say I don't know if there is a better way. It could be.

Comment: It's the best method in this case :)

Comment: @BraveVN you can move keys to `array` to make this line a bit shorter: `keys = %i[user_id first_name last_name phone_number addres]` and then just: `user_info.values_at(*keys)`

Comment: awesome @AlexGolubenko, you're my hero :D

Comment: @AlexGolubenko 2 shorter lines are always better than 1 long line :D

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an OpenStruct, like so:

```
o=OpenStruct.new(user_info)
```

Then, you can access variables like so:

```
o.user_id
```

etc